# upgrade MSDB only?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016, ssis, upgrade, msdb

good morning.

we currently are running on SQL server 2008 r2 and going to Sql server 2016.  we are told we cannot do an in place upgrade and will have to restore all SSIS and jobs manually (script, etc) b/c cannot directly restore MSDB.

My question - can I backup the msdb, restore on a new, blank database, and then in place upgrade that msdb to SQL Server 2016....after that is complete, backup and restore that upgraded msdb back to the new 2016 instance where it belongs?

I'm not sure if this would work as I'm sure msdb contains more info than just jobs and ssis, so I'm afraid it would hose the environment.

Thoughts?

Comment: after reading what I wrote, it didnt make sense, lol.  our 2008 r2 is being upgraded to 2016 but we are told they will not move SSIS and jobs.  can I just upgrade the msdb by restoring to new instance and in place upgrading only that?

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could try, but why would you? Since you are worried about Jobs, it would be much easier to script those out. Here are a couple of methods:

- [Using SSMS](https://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Scripting%20all%20Agent%20Jobs%20Using%20SQL%20Server%20Management%20Studio%20(SSMS).aspx)
- Use [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/commands/) to [migrate the jobs](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Copy-DbaAgentJob)

MSDB does more than just hold the agent jobs, schedules, and alerts. It also has information about your backups, service broker, database mail, etc that may not be the same in your new environment.